# JNI how to pass value to a pointer parameter

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working on Android development. I have a native method with a pointer parameter:

```
int writeData(unsigned char* readbuff, int length)
```

I want to pass value to the address readbuff point to. I did it like this:

```
int readData(unsigned char* readbuff, int length){//unsigned
   *readbuff = 'a';
   return 0;
    }
```

But it failed with:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x74e9a36e (code=2), thread 14078 (Thread-1916)
```

My question is how can I change the value in readbuff? I have searched a lot, but still can't get the answer. Please help me!
Thank you very very much!

**EDIT**:
Here is my new code:

```
int readData(unsigned char* readbuff){
   JNIEnv *env;
   unsigned char* tmpbuff = "abc";
   if(readbuff==NULL||length < 4)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "error", "readbuff is null");
   else
       memcpy ( readbuff, tmpbuff, 3 );
}
```

Now the method is called like this:

```
void test(){
   unsigned char* readbuff = "this is jni"; 
       readData(readbuff);
}
```

But I still got same error...
Please help!

**Partially Solved!**
I tried a lot and finally get the app run. I just change the test() like this:

```
void test(){
   unsigned char readbuff[11] = "this is jni"; //edit here
       readData(readbuff);
}
```

But I'm not good in C, who can tell me why readbuff[11] work but *readbuff not?
Thanks again and again!

Comment: You don't check `length`, what if it's `0` or `readbuff` turns out to be `null`? In any case the signal tells you you're actually trying to modify content at `readbuff` but the system doesn't allow you to. Most likely because you're passing an invalid pointer (or no pointer value at all).

Comment: Thank you mabi. I add check code to the method. the readbuff is not null. But same error

Comment: You don't use JNI here. This is just one C function calling another. If you use JNI, e.g. calling a C function from Java, you need a method declaration on the Java side and an appropriate implementation on the C side.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, I use JNI. I just not print the Java and jni interface code here. Because I thought this problem has nothing to do with java side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between

```
unsigned char* readbuff = "this is jni";
```

and

```
unsigned char readbuff[11] = "this is jni";
```

is the first one points to a string literal, which must not be modified. The second one is a local char array containing the same string, but the char array may be freely modified.

However, be aware that the array is too small by one character. It is missing space for the final NUL byte. If you want to have an array exactly as long as needed, you can say

```
unsigned char readbuff[] = "this is jni";
```

*Update:*

To do the same dynamically, you can do

```
void test(){
    unsigned char* readbuff = malloc(256);
    readData(readbuff);
}
```

But you must not forget to [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the memory eventually.

Comment: Thank you every much! Does that mean malloc first and giving the address to *readbuff have the same effect as readbuff[11]?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **memcpy** instead of the assignment of = 'a' (assuming your talking about C, you used a lot of tags there ^^)

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Comment: int readData(unsigned char* readbuff, int length){//unsigned
    JNIEnv *env;
    unsigned char* tmpbuff = "abc";
    memcpy ( readbuff, tmpbuff, 3 );

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I added memcpy as above, but same error.

Comment: Using memcpy instead of direct assignment, doesn't change anything here. If the memory pointer is not initialized or not accessible, it will give a segmentation fault nevertheless.